# PHP divide rectangle (image) into grid?

Tags: php, image

EDIT:

Is there a way to jumble arround the pixelated elements? If I have a grid of lets say 100x100 - then the pixels get very small and you can see the image sort of. So I'd like to jumble the pixelated parts. Any idea?

---

I'm trying to use PHP to divide an image into an equal grid, so that I could pixelate it into even parts.

It has to do with a sort of game. There is an image uploaded by some user, and I want it to be divided into x blocks (the user selects how many blocks there should be), each of the blocks would then be pixelated. When other users complete some task - one part of the pixelated block is revealed, until all pixelated parts are gone and you're left with the original image. I really don't care if the grid elements are squares, or rectangles - I just want them to be even.

As my starting points, I'm using the answer on this question [PHP image pixelate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936601/php-image-pixelate)

To determine the x and y pixel size, I'm using this formula:

```
$gridElements = 9;
$pixelate_x = $width/sqrt($gridElements);
$pixelate_y = $height/sqrt($gridElements);
```

I've noticed that when using a number, whose square root is an integer - I get a more even grid.. But it's not perfect.

When trying out with a 9 block grid, and using a 1160x680 image, I get the following:

[image: Image 1]

It may appear to look even, but the last row is bigger than the top 2 rows.

When I scale it to 16, the difference is quite obvious

[image]

And when trying out a 400 element grid (20x20) the 21th row appears.

[image]

So .. It's not working very well, I do want the grid to be even. Does anyone have any idea of how this could be done?

Comment: Looks like that's actually row 20, not 21?

Comment: You'd have to check whether `image_height / number_of_vertical_blocks` is `integer` which shouldn't be a problem with 4x4 or 20x20... are you sure your `image_height` = 680?

Comment: Yes sorry I was counting another attempt.. Yes the 20th row is cut :/

Yes the image height is 680, you can copy the image URL and open it in a new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because 1160 doesn't really divides itself very well, even by 3 (yes, it is not equal when using 3x3 grid either). Your greatest enemy here are integers

Comment: Well I've tried using widths & heights that have a square root equal to an integer, so my new image size is 1156 x 676, yet I still have the same cut off issues

Comment: try this:
http://pastie.org/6371547
it resizes the image first, then iterates over it using integer-ized pixelates.
commented out some lines, and in my opinion you can even cut out a ot of code from there ;)