# How to pixelate an image?

Tags: codeigniter, image-processing

i am really new into image manipulation. Actually what i am supposed to do is to convert an image into pixelate form of image. Bellow is the input and output of sample example;

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

So, Let me know if out there is some good tutorial for image manipulation in JavaScript or Action Script. This will late be implemented with PHP framework codeigniter

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP image pixelate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936601/php-image-pixelate)

Comment: try implement this: http://fabricjs.com/image-filters/

Answer (score 0):

For a simple pixelation filter, you can try divide the image into blocks (the big resulting pixels) which are k×k pixels, and then replace all the pixels in each block with the average value of the pixels in that block.

Comment: I think an additional step will need to be done to achieve the sample result.  The image isn't just blocky, it has gaps between points like a old print.  Maybe only set the center of the block to the average value and the rest (border) of the block to white.

Comment: May I ask how you got the output image? did you apply a fiter?